# Invalid syntax near '.' even when using parameter in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL query:

```
Select distinct
    cols.referenced_entity_name 
from  
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs   
outer apply
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N'.' + object_name(objs.referencing_id), N'OBJECT') as cols 
where  
    objs.referencing_id = object_id('viewname')
```

This returns me a list of dependencies for a given view

This query works in SQL. However when I put it into a c# class as such

```
Select distinct 
    cols.referenced_entity_name as depedency
from
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs 
outer apply
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N@period + object_name(objs.referencing_id), N@object ) as cols 
where 
    objs.referencing_id = object_id(@view)
```

with the parameters being `@period` = `.`  and `@object` = OBJECT and `@view` = viewname, I get an exception

> invalid syntax near '.' .

I had originally not had the '.' as a parameter and sent it through as just '.' but it rejected that as well ( I escaped the '  so \'.\' so that the resulting string was just '.')

Kind of stumped as to what I can do to get the query to work...as I said it works fine if I just run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

I am open to an alternative query to get me the same results btw I got this query from [Determine table referenced in a view in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308252/determine-table-referenced-in-a-view-in-sql-server)

and it returns what I am looking for which is a query that returns a view dependencies and as I said it works in query analyzer but cant get it to function when passed through a `SqlCommand` object in C#

EDIT::

OK I dug into the views referenced in the query above and for the life of me I cant figure out why this query wouldnt just give me the same results

```
  Select referenced_entity_name as dependancy from sys.sql_expression_dependencies where referencing_id = object_id('viewname')
```

So far as I can tell it is giving me the same results with a much cleaner query but I'm not exactly an expert in the system views.

Can anyone tell me if they believe this should give me the same results unerringly?

Because if it does it eliminates the need for the N'.'  which is causing me the grief trying to parameterize it in c#

Comment: `N@object` is *not* valid syntax, simply use `@object`, or better yet simply `'OBJECT'` since it's constant. Same for the period.

Comment: even if I remove the N  in front of the @period parameter I still get invalid syntax '.'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725548/sql-server-all-object-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is that you need to use @object in your query, but when you're setting your parameter in C# you can define the type:

```
System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar
```

Which will make it so you don't have to use the N prefix.

Another thing to watch out for is that you want to use `"."` and not `'.'` as they are two different things: string and char.

Comment: wont let me edit my first comment for some reason  here is what I meant to say  

in the version I am currently using I parameterized them and I have removed the N   so that the query is  @period  which is set into the cmd object as  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(para_name, parameter_values);  and teh value I pass in is simply .  no quotes

Comment: Also I tried using "." and it still return the same invalid syntax near '.'